# Unable to connect to JIRA over HTTPS server using the Perl JIRA::Client::Automated

Tags: perl, rest, https, jira

I do not use a proxy.

Here is my code:

```
use JIRA::Client::Automated;
my $jira = JIRA::Client::Automated->new(https://myserver.com, "user", "password");
```

And the error response is:

> Unable to GET /jira/rest/api/latest/issue/DCS-51191: 500 Can't connect
>   to myserver.com:443 Can't connect to myserver.com:443
>
> Bad file descriptor at
>   C:/Users/Fred/applis_portables/Strawberry_Perl/perl/vendor/lib/LWP/Protocol/http.pm
>   line 47.
>
> at createPage2.pl line 16.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that there is a self signed certificate on JIRA server. To bypass, I added following code:

my $jira_ua = $jira->ua();
$jira_ua->ssl_opts( verify_hostname => 0 );

Answer (score 0):

The error doesn't look like a JIRA::Client::Automated error. It's generated by LWP::UserAgent and usually means exactly what is shown.

Do you have a self signed certificate on your server?

Did you try to open that URL in in your browser? https://myserver.com:443 (exactly as you provide it to the module).

Try using curl **from your webserver**:
`curl -vvv https://myserver.com/jira/rest/api/latest/issue/DCS-51191`

Maybe it's just a missing *www.* prefix in your server URL?

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
I don't know if there is a self signed certificate on the server (server is managed by IT team).
When I open the URL in my browser, my JIRA dashboard is displayed. curl command displays :

curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate in certificate chain
More details here: http://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html

Comment: You found your problem :) Probably not solvable in JIRA::Client::Automated.